# Lightest setup to sell only digital content with no physical products?

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce, files

I'm looking for recommendations on how to setup Drupal 7 with the fewest modules so I can charge users to Buy Digital Content (Book Pages) on my site.

I will eventually have several books, and users will need to pay for each one to read (view) them. There are no files to be downloaded here, I will actually try to prevent users from copying the content; they should only have access to the Book.

I looked at the recommended [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), but it seems very much like overkill (many unused features like shipping, packing, inventory) for what I want to do. Not sure it can (easily) handle Digital Content.

If there is no simple solution, can this be easily done in Drupal Commerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get by using Drupal Commerce with just the core modules, some custom Rules, and your preferred payment gateway module. The modules and features you pointed to (shipping, inventory, etc.) and the ones you didn't point out have nothing to do with Drupal Commerce itself. They're all optional contributed modules and don't have to be added if you don't need them.

It's possible you saw a demo site running Commerce Kickstart 2.x. That is a distribution of Drupal that includes Drupal Commerce and a wide variety of contributed modules to make it function more like a robust eCommerce application out of the box. At its core, Drupal Commerce is much lighter weight, and I think you'll find its compatibility with Rules combined with the Content Access / Access Control List modules to be very helpful in selling access to digital content on your site.

Comment: Out of the box, Drupal Commerce (drupal.org/commerce) is basically a digital only shop. It has no concepts of shipping without contrib.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I will try to install Commerce Core and see if it does what I need. Is there a distribution or module for just the Core modules?

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand now - you are suggesting just installing the base Commerce module found at: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce , right?

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because it comes closest to what I was trying to do (I guess Ubercart would have worked as well). However, for this use case, we have decided to use a domain specific online tutorial platform instead of a Drupal solution. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: Sweet, thanks @banncee! Really makes me want to go back to creating a "Content Privée" hosted Drupal that solves this use case. ^_^

Comment: @Ryan Szrama, yes, it would be nice. There appear to be a lot of players in this space. Check out: Thinkific, Teachable, Ruzuku, etc. I played around with Thinkific, and it is very easy to use, slick!

Comment: @RyanSzrama I want to display products, but do not want to show prices and the cart. I am on drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [payment](https://www.drupal.org/project/payment) (API), there's fe. a [paypal](https://www.drupal.org/project/paypal_payment) integration, among others -  with this you can skip the shop overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Below are 2 possible alternatives (options) you may want to look at.

## Option 1: A lightweight e-shop

**If** you're only looking for a simple and lightweight e-commerce solution, **Then** have a looking at the [Light Shop](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightshop) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> - Session-stored basket.
> - Adding to basket and its subsequent editing/checkout process is done using AJAX. Also it works fine when JavaScript is turned off.
> - Node based shopping. As the product can be assigned to any node type. One or more. With full support Field API features (regarding nodes).
> - Orders history. For each order will be created a separate node.
> - There is no dependence on other modules.
> - Full support for working with anonymous users
> - Integration with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

## Option 2: A simple shopping cart

**If** you're only looking for a shopping cart (as in your title), **Then** have a looking at the [Basic Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Basic cart is a very simple shopping cart / checkout process for Drupal, that just sends 2 emails after each order. Along with the shopping cart, this module also provides a block where you can view your cart's content. It's ideal for small websites with only a few products or other content types being sold, for example touristic offers.
>
> **Main difference from Ubercart and Commerce:**
>
> The main difference from Ubercart and Commerce is the possibility of choosing the content types that can be added to the cart. It also doesn't bother you with the Product SKU, that can be a pain when you have just a few products.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - The possibility of choosing the content types that can be added to the cart.
> - The possibility of sending, or not, an email to the customer once an order is placed.
> - Custom email messages for both the site administrator and the customer, along with the order details.
> - Order registration and listing in the administration area using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
> - Integration with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.
> - A block with the contents of your shopping cart.

Here is a screenshot of it (note the "**Checkout**" button also ...):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. For Light Shop, it says: "Limitations No payment methods. Only e-mail notification." So how would I actually charge people using CC or PayPal?

Comment: I tried Light Shop, but it doesn't do what I need. It shows a 'Add to Basket' button on my premium content node types; I want to only show the user those nodes after they have paid.

Comment: Looks like Basic Cart also has the same problems in my use case as Light Shop